# Setting a datafame into table in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I need help ton find a solution to my probleme.

I'm working in Rmarkdown and my output is an word document. So, i'm doing report and I encounter a problem in the display table and show it.

Here's an exemple of a data(iris):

```
data(iris)
```

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

First create the data.

```
data(iris)
dat <- as.data.frame(iris)
```

Now you use dat for the tables.

I like to use `flextable` or `kable`, the first is from the flextable package and the last from knitr. That is, either,

```
knitr::kable(dat)
```

or

```
flextable::flextable(dat)
```

Comment: how can i center the table ?

Comment: knitr::kable(dat) %>% knitr::kable_styling(position = "center"). If you find the solution helpful please accept it.

Comment: Thanks u, but it doen't work with my data

Comment: Can you explain why? or atleast upload an example of your data?